# Save and Load Data from Amazon Cloud (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, swift4, amazon-cognito

I have following data model, and i am saving and loading data with userdefaults in Swift (Local) successfully. However, instead of locally, i want to save and load data directly from AWS Cloud. Which service i have to use; Cognito User Sync data or DynamoDB or S3?? I have only checked Cognito user sync, i think that's only for strings.

While considering the method, the following requirements must be met:

a) all data i want to collect in one table to summarise values

b) each user will retrieve their own data from there.

c) i need that each user has to share his own data with another user, is it possible? i will be glad if you let me know about which method i have to follow.

```
    static var networks = [Network]()

    struct Network: Codable {

            var label: Label
            let topic: String
            var rssi: String
            var ssid: String
            var IP: String
            var MAC: String
            var result: String

            init(label lbl: Label, topic: String, rssi: String, ssid: String, IP: String, MAC: String, result: String) {
                self.label = lbl
                self.topic = topic
                self.rssi = rssi
                self.ssid = ssid
                self.IP = IP
                self.MAC = MAC
                self.result = result
            }
    }
Local save & load functions;

    static func saveDefaults() {
          let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(networks)
          UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "network")
    }

    static func loadDefaults() {
          if let decoded = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "network") {
                networks = try! JSONDecoder().decode([NETWORK].self, from: decoded as! Data)
          }
    }
```

Comment: Is the sharing permanent? Or can the owner revoke the share access?

Comment: Sharing will be when user wants (call another cognito username), as like to share iot device with different user.

Comment: Without the sharing requirement c, DynamoDb with fine grained access control would be the obvious choice. But with sharing...

Comment: For a temporarily, each user data (as Json Value) uploaded to Cognito Datasets and it is works well, for sync of stored data. If i can succeed to share each Json data with using Lambda function, may be it can be, right?

Comment: Well yes. Technically, u can use a lambda to retrieve datasets based on an IdentityId & you can expose it using API Gateway, if needed

Comment: I will be glad if you can let me know about the manual (or sources) how to expose with API Gateway, thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html

Comment: Thanks for it, i will try it, hope we can see some alternative solutions..

Comment: Cool. Good luck. And write your solution when u get it to work

Comment: Dear agent420, i have one question about the sync of Dataset, for ex, when i made some changes on Json Dataset on AWS Console. How i can sync the updated Dataset with iOS app, finally iOS app does not have any listener. And it still goes on with old dataset

Comment: U mean you want all changes to Cognito Sync datasets to be pushed to devices in real time?

Comment: U can use the Push Sync feature for that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/push-sync.html

Comment: Yes this is for exceptional situation but i wanted to learn how i can push it to app

Comment: Ok.. Push Sync fits this requirement

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response...

Comment: Dear agent420, do you have some solution for forex. i will have 10.000 data sets and i want to list it with lambda function (as seen in the link http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-sync.html#CognitoSync.Client.list_datasets), you know the limitation for max results?

Comment: and how i can get such number of datasets in one list (with one function)?

Comment: For Cognito Sync, there are certain limits - Maximum number of datasets per identity :20; Maximum number of records per dataset: 1024; Max size of Dataset: 1 Mb;

Comment: So, based on this the MaxResult can vary from 0 to 19. 0 being all 20 datasets & 1- 19 being the actual limits

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/API_ListDatasets.html

Comment: I was planning to create different datasets for each user(Dataset name specific), regarding to structure of my struct (struct name = record name) as seen in the code.  So, how i can solve the issue? i have to make the name of the struct dynamic belongs to each user?? is it possible?

Comment: static var networks should be dynamic but how?

Comment: Sure u can but whats the point. Dataset is already linked to a unique IdentityId

Comment: if number of Dataset is not limited, yes it could be fine, it could be created for each username but if its limited with only 20, i have to increase the number of records inside Dataset, right?

Comment: Lets continue our discussion on chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158191/temp-room

Comment: i have reputation limitation, thats why i couldn't enter the room, any other alternative to talk ?

Comment: Ok.. then could you not store your whole struct as a Stringified key value pair?

Comment: i was planning to add some code to iOS App, to detect the number of records in each dataset, may be it can be solution, don't know its possible or not

Comment: Sorry about this but it is already past midnight here 1:30 am. Try out some solutions and get back if u face any issues. Also, this site is not for these kind of discussions. You can always post your query on AWS forums. You may get more relevant help there. :)